# Python multiprocessing takes too long to complete after main process has finished

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to familiarize myself with multiprocessing so I used a brute force search to find a string.

The script works as expected and due to the use of an iterator RAM usage is pretty good. What I don't understand is what is happening after the "password" has been found. It always takes double the time for the script to exit (in this example 70sec for finding the password and 160sec to complete) where, as far as I understand, the only thing it still has to do is terminate all the processes.

Is this what is happening or there is something else?

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing as mp
import string
import time

# start timer
tStart = time.time()

userPass = 'mypass'

def getPassword(passList):
    str = ''.join(passList)
    if userPass == str:
        print('\n')
        print('~~~ CRACKED ~~~')
        print('User password is {}'.format(str))
        print('Cracked password in {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.time() - tStart))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # possible characters used in password
    chars = list(string.ascii_lowercase)    

    # get all character combinations
    allPasswords = itertools.product(chars, repeat=len(userPass))

    # calculate optimum chunk number
    totalComb = len(chars) ** len(userPass)
    nChunks = int(max(1, divmod(totalComb, mp.cpu_count() * 4)[0]))

    with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(getPassword, allPasswords, chunksize=nChunks):
            if result == userPass:
                pool.terminate()
                break
            del result # trying to reduce memory usage
    tEnd = time.time()
    tElapsed = tEnd - tStart

    print('Total elapsed time {:.3f} seconds'.format(tElapsed))
```

Comment: You are ASSUMING that `imap_unordered` will return the results in the order in which they finish.  I don't believe Python makes that guarantee at all.  I think it just picks one and waits for it.  You might consider using a Queue to return results.  You can wait on an item from the queue, then kill the rest of the processes.

Comment: Your chunk size is humongous, that might have something to do with it

Comment: You asked why the program takes so long to complete and I think you didn't get the correct answer.  You seem to be hoping that a call to pool.terminate() will stop all of the pool's activity, but that just isn't the case.  The implementation of Pool in the standard library creates 3 additional threads, two Queues, and some callbacks of various kinds.  It's very complicated.  There is almost no way to cleanly shut it down before all of its processing is complete.  As far as I can tell, there is no way that the Pool class will do what you want.

Comment: @PaulCornelius The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate) says `terminate` *"Stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work"*. Does the pool not just discard those additional things then? I mean, if the workers don't do anything anymore...

Comment: @PaulCornelius I think you're right, the `terminate` doesn't seem to make any difference. If I remove it and leave the `break` the result is the same.

Comment: I think the documentation is a bit sketchy here.  There are other ways to submit work to Process objects without calling one of the `map` functions - perhaps in those cases the documented behavior is correct.  But looking at the code for imap_unordered, I don't see how there's a way to stop all that machinery immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `getPassword` function return the string (at least in the success case). Right now it always returns the default `None`, so `result == userPass` is never true and `pool.terminate()` is never executed.

Also, you might want to use a much smaller `chunksize`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that's a big mistake. I made it return the `getPassword` return the string always but the behavior didn't change. Now the RAM is maxed out and the response is this
~~~ CRACKED ~~~

User password is mypass

Cracked password in 82.001 seconds

Total elapsed time 196.723 seconds

So, again it doesn't seem to terminate.

Comment: @2nsis Before `pool.terminate()`, print a message and the time. With your original, that shouldn't occur at all. With returning the string, it should. Does it? And what's that time? Also, try using a much smaller chunk size, let's say 100,000. How does that affect things?

Comment: Yes, in the original the `pool.terminate()` is never executed whereas now it does. With the chunk size calculation, I have the results are as I mentioned above, double the time from finding the result until exiting. With a chunk size of 100k 0.1sec from finding the result until exiting. I've noticed before that it's very sensitive to chunk size.

Comment: @2nsis So it's all good now, or still some problem?

Comment: With 100,000 it works OK but the behavior is strange because with 1,000 it also works fine, but with 10,000 it takes a lot of time. In any case, that's another issue of optimizing the chunk size.
Thanks for your help!